# SharePoint Drop down list control throws selected index error

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I have an error like below. I have inserted only the SharePoint drop down control alone in my application while clicking save it throws this error

SharePoint drop down control:

```
<SharePoint:DVDropDownList  ID="ddl_Application" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ></SharePoint:DVDropDownList>
```

'ddl_Application' has a SelectedIndex which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value.

I don't know what i did wrong kindly help me to resolve this,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your case "Source" doesn't return any values.
So it can't set a value for SelectedIndex because there is nothing to select.

Check your list if there are any entries.

Comment: i didn't bind any values for the controls just added the empty controls alone for that itself it throws exception

Comment: I didn't use list and nothing just a drop down control only while click save it throws the above error i didn't made anything with that control its empty

Comment: This sol. sets AppendDataBoundItems="true" on the DropDownList & creates one nullable ListItem so that your DropDownList will bind even when the field in the table is null.
The following snippet would provide n option that would be selected when the Application field is null.

<SharePoint:DropDownList ID="ddl_Application" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="SubjectDataSource" 
    DataTextField="fullname" DataValueField="empl_Id" 
    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Application") %>' 
    AppendDataBoundItems="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="" /><
</SharePoint:DropDownList>